# Trying to adjust existing app's storyboard to work with iPhone 6 and 6+ screen sizes

Tags: xcode, storyboard, ios8, autolayout

I have created new storyboard with auto layout enabled (image below).

[image: Auto layout enabled]

The strange thing is the entire view is proportionally stretched. I can't figure out how to leave ratio 1:1. It is not about using auto layout I believe.

The images show the problem:

This image comes from clean app. It shows view on iPhone 6+ simulator. As you see the table cells are 1:1 (smaller then the following example). Also the `status bar` is fitting with size at the home screen.

[image: iPhone 6+ simulator - clean app]

This images comes from a new storyboard in existing app. The set up of the story board is exactly the same as in clean app. Moreover the `.plist` config is matching. As you can notice the cells are bigger, and the `status bar` is also bigger.

[image: iPhone 6+ simulator - existing app]

Is this a simulator bug?
I haven't got the device myself, but it was tested on device (6+) and the problem spotted.
What am I missing. Is it auto layout issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have figured out the issue.

Basically if you face the same problem, just create `.xib` file for lunch view. Previously it it was image that we needed to add. With iOS8 it is `.xib` file that needs to be defined in `Launch Screen File` in `General` tab.